# Why Pipeline Job is triggered although there is no change in SCM

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

I am setting up a pipeline job for my project and what I would like to do is to setup the job to ping to the SCM every two minites to check if there is change, if yes then build the job using pipeline script.

Here is my pipeline job configuration:

[image]

and the pipeline script:

```
pipeline {
    agent any 
    options { 
        disableConcurrentBuilds() 
    } 
    tools {
        maven 'Maven 3.6'
    }
    stages {
        stage('Git Checkout') {
            steps {
                sh 'echo "Git Checkout"'
                checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: 'master']], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [], submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'my-credential', url: 'my-git-url']]])
            }
        }
        stage('Maven Build') {
            steps {
                sh 'mvn clean deploy -s $WORKSPACE/custom-config/settings.xml -Dsettings.security=$WORKSPACE/custom-config/settings-security.xml'
            }
        }
        stage('Maven Build and SonarQube Analysis') {
            steps {
                withSonarQubeEnv('Sonar Qube') {
                    sh 'mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.projectKey=com.product:backend'
                }
            }
        }
        stage('SonarQube Quality Gate') {
            steps {
                timeout(time: 10, unit: 'MINUTES') {
                    waitForQualityGate abortPipeline: true
                }
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        failure {
            mail bcc: '', body: "See ${env.BUILD_URL}", cc: '', charset: 'UTF-8', from: '', mimeType: 'text/html', replyTo: '', subject: "Build failed in Jenkins: ${env.JOB_NAME} #${env.BUILD_NUMBER}", to: "my.email@gmail.com";
        }
        unstable {
            mail bcc: '', body: "See ${env.BUILD_URL}", cc: '', charset: 'UTF-8', from: '', mimeType: 'text/html', replyTo: '', subject: "Build unstable in Jenkins: ${env.JOB_NAME} #${env.BUILD_NUMBER}", to: "my.email@gmail.com";
        }
    }
}
```

Everything is working fine excepts that the job is triggered every two minutes although there is nothing changes in the master branch which I have setup in the script. Can anyone help me here to prevent this action. I would like the job to be triggered only when there is change in SCM. Thank you very much!

Comment: You hide the `branch specifier`, can you add it ? Apparently you only want the `master` to be built, this where you specify it. Also, you can go the details of the build that wasn't supposed to start and look at the `SCM changes` to see what are the actual changes

Comment: Can you also add the Build Trigger Configurations?

Comment: Hi @ArnaudClaudel, in the branch specifier I have another branch, and in this branch is my Jenkinsfile located

Comment: Hi @bilcy do you mean the Build Trigger in the Jenkins Interface or in the Pipeline Code?

Comment: I think that the build will trigger when there are changes in the branch you specify in the UI. Again look at the build details to see what actually triggered it

Comment: I see, this means I have to specify the branch in the UI same as the branch in the pipeline code? Is it right?

Comment: I meant the build trigger configuration in the Jenkins UI.